# Calling the values out from CSV file for aGraphEngine (Android)

Tags: android, achartengine

I am trying to obtain the 4th and 5th elements from the csv data and use it as a dataset for the 2nd (mDatasetNormal) and third graph line.  I was able to figure out how to obtain the data from the 3rd element however the rest is an issue.

My questions are:

1. How to read the Heappy_log.csv and than use the arrayList to obtain data for the graph?
2. After data is obtained from the csv how to use it for the same graph?

CSV file content:

> Aug-30-2014,08:06 AM, 0,0,0
>
> Sep-05-2014,08:09 AM, 0,3,2
>
> Sep-05-2014,08:09 AM, 0,3,2

Whole code:

```
 public class Chart extends Activity {

ArrayList<Integer> stateList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> normalList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//Chart creation
private GraphicalView mChart, mChartNormal;

/**
 * Create multiple data sets to be used on graph
 */
//Data sets used for graph manipulation
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
private XYSeries mCurrentSeries;
private XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer;

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDatasetNormal = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRendere2 = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
private XYSeries mCurrentSeriesNormal;
private XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRendererNormal;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Code which makes activity full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart);
    readHappyLog();

}

//Create a method for the aChart engine
private void initChart() {

    //Series description for both charts
    mCurrentSeries = new XYSeries("Amount of happy kids");
    mDataset.addSeries(mCurrentSeries);

    mCurrentSeriesNormal = new XYSeries("Amount of normal kids");
    mDatasetNormal.addSeries(mCurrentSeriesNormal);

    //Renderer for happy kids
    mCurrentRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mCurrentRenderer);

    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(24);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(20);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
    mRenderer.setXTitle(" Date of practice ");
    mRenderer.setYTitle(" Number of kids ");

    //Renderer for normal kids
    mCurrentRendererNormal = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mRendere2.addSeriesRenderer(mCurrentRendererNormal);
    mRendere2.setYTitle("Number of normal kids");

    //Applying background
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(20);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0.0);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0.0);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(24);

    //Sets the color of the graph line and width
    mCurrentRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mCurrentRenderer.setLineWidth(10f);
    mCurrentRendererNormal.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    mCurrentRenderer.setLineWidth(10f);
}


//Add x and y data into the graph and mark the x graph

private void addHappyData(){
    Integer x = 0;
    for (Integer happy : stateList ){
        mCurrentSeries.add(x += 10, happy);
    }
}

//Add x and y for normal to the graph

private void addNormalData(){
    Integer y = 0;
    for (Integer happy : normalList ){
        mCurrentSeriesNormal.add(y += 10, happy);

        }

    }

// Draw the graph
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    if (mChart == null){
        initChart();
        addHappyData();
        addNormalData();

        //Set chart type
        mChart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset , mRenderer);
        layout.addView(mChart);

        mChartNormal = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDatasetNormal,mRendere2);
        layout.addView(mChartNormal);



    }else{
        mChart.repaint();
        mChartNormal.repaint();

    }
}

/**
 * create a method to read the happy log
 */
private void readHappyLog(){
    String FILENAME = "happy_log.csv"; //Open the file name under this string
    FileInputStream inputStream = null; // Import the package
    String temp;
    String[] a;


    try {
        inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME); //Open file desceriptor (Object)

        byte[] reader = new byte [inputStream.available() ]; //Everything from disk is byte

        while (inputStream.read( reader ) != -1 ){}

        //Reader array now holds the entire file
        //Needs to create scanner in order to read the file properly
        Scanner s = new Scanner (new String(reader));
        s.useDelimiter(("\\n"));

        while (s.hasNext()){

            //Split the string lines if he sees comma value
            temp = s.next();
            a = temp.split(",");


            stateList.add(Integer.parseInt(a[2]));
            normalList.add(Integer.parseInt(a[3]));

        }
        s.close();

    }catch (Exception e ){
        Log.e("Chart", e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        if (inputStream != null ){
            try{ inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                Log.e( "Chart", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First Read Csv and Sort value form Srting

Comment: But that is already done in the private void readHappyLog()? Reading is done with scanner and the values are also sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Problem solved:
//Add x and y data to series

private void addHappyData() {
    Integer x = 0;
    for (Integer happy : stateList) {
        mCurrentSeries.add(x += 10, happy);
    }
}
private void addNormalData() {
    Integer x = 0;
    for (Integer normal : normalList) {
        mNormalSeries.add(x += 10, normal);
    }
}

// Draw the graph
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    if (mChart == null) {
        initChart();
        addHappyData();
        addNormalData();

        //Set chart type
        mChart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer);
        layout.addView(mChart);

    } else {
        mChart.repaint();

    }
}

/**
 * create a method to read the happy log
 */
private void readHappyLog() {
    String FILENAME = "happy_log.csv"; //Open the file name under this string
    FileInputStream inputStream = null; // Import the package
    String temp;
    String[] a;


    try {
        inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME); //Open file desceriptor (Object)

        byte[] reader = new byte[inputStream.available()]; //Everything from disk is byte

        while (inputStream.read(reader) != -1) {
        }

        //Reader array now holds the entire file
        //Needs to create scanner in order to read the file properly
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new String(reader));
        s.useDelimiter(("\\n"));

        while (s.hasNext()) {

            //Split the string lines if he sees comma value
            temp = s.next();
            a = temp.split(",");

            stateList.add(Integer.parseInt(a[2]));
            normalList.add(Integer.parseInt(a[3]));


        }
        s.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Chart", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Chart", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}